# Transform YYYYMM to DD-MM-YYY SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a column in sql server like 201801. How can I transform this in DD-MM-YYYY?
Thank you!

Comment: What date is that? Datatype? And any chance you fix the schema and use a date datatype instead of strings or ints?

Comment: What came up on Google when you researched transforming strings to datetimes?

Comment: It's a string and I need to transform in a date format but to keep it as a string.

Comment: Again....what date is that? And why oh why are sticking with using strings? This should be a date and the front end should handle the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date column has `varchar` type, then you can do :

```
select convert(varchar(12), cast(col+'01' as date), 105)
from table t;
```